# (British) National Rail - does Anytime Day Return allow 4 trips?

Tags: trains, uk

I can't remember if the tickets are swallowed or not - will I be able to go from A to B and back twice on an *Anytime* Day Return fare?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a permitted use of the tickets; you should get two returns, or, in a region where one is permitted, a day travelcard (in London), day saver (in Merseyside), etc.

If there's a gate at the destination station, they will be swallowed.

If your train has a conductor, the tickets will be marked so you can't reuse them.

In theory, DOO trains operate only to gated stations, so you would always have a gate or a conductor.

Comment: Ah yeah thanks, that was stupid of me, obviously the marking/punching is more the issue.

Comment: "In theory, DOO trains operate only to gated stations" -- and in practice that's not quite how it works, especially given that nominally gated stations might have open gates some or all of the time, more or less predictably. But knowing this only leads to a discussion of whether you'd get away with fare-dodging, not whether or not the journey is permitted by the ticket.